# Reading from CSV using Apache commons.csv library in Hadoop project

Tags: java, maven, csv, hadoop

I'm working on project and I use:

- Java version: java version 1.8.0_121
- Hadoop version: Apache Hadoop 2.7.3
- Maven version: Apache Maven 3.3.9
- CSV commons library 1.5-SNAPSHOT

I face problem using apache.commons.csv library in a hadoop project. The purpose of the code is to compute some values (field1, field2) and pass the as input to a reducer.
The code of the mapper is as follows:

```
 import java.io.*;
 import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
 import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
 import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
 import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
 import org.apache.commons.csv.*;
 import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit;

 import java.util.regex.Pattern;
 import java.util.regex.Matcher;

 public class Mapper1
     extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

     public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
     throws IOException, InterruptedException {

     Reader in = new FileReader("path/to/a/CSV/file.csv");

     Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.RFC4180.parse(in);
         for (CSVRecord record : records) {
         Text field1 = new Text(record.get(1));
         IntWritable field2 = new IntWritable(Integer.valueOf(record.get(9)) * Integer.valueOf((10)));

         }
     context.write(field1,field2);
     }

 }
```

The code is based on the documetation of the library found here:
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html
in the section "accessing column values by index"

When I'm trying to built the project using `mvn compile` I get the following compilation error for the mapper:

> [ERROR] /path/to/project/src/main/java/Mapper1.java:[24,9] cannot find  symbol 
>   [ERROR] symbol:   variable field1  
>   [ERROR] location: class Mapper1  
>   [ERROR] /path/to/project/src/main/java/Mapper1.java:[27,9] cannot find symbol 
>  
>   [ERROR] symbol: variable field2  
>   [ERROR] location:class Mapper1  
>   [ERROR] /path/to/project/src/main/java/Mapper1.java:[30,19] cannot find symbol

The pom.xml for Maven is the following:

```
<project>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ba.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <hadoop.version>2.7.3</hadoop.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>org.apache.commons:commons-csv</include>
                                </includes>
                            </artifactSet>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I also tried to use the `record.set()` method as I saw somewhere online like this, although the syntax seems a bit a weird to me:

```
field1 = new Text(record.get(1));
record.set(field1);
```

But it didn't worked either..

Comment: Your classpath is likely wrong, what command, tools and config do you use for building and running your program?

Comment: I edited the question above to include some information. The classpath is set right as I ran other projects before without any problem..

Comment: Ok what command are you using to run the main class?

Comment: I just used mvn compile. If the compile of the project was successful, I would then create the appropriate .jar using mvn package and give it as input to the hadoop to run the map reduce job

Comment: So if you try to run "hadoop jar <jarFileName> <mainClassname> <AnyCommandLineArguements>" it outputs the expected result?

Comment: Where do you declare `field1` and `field2`?

Comment: @Tome I tried Text field1 = new Text(..) and IntWritable field2= new IntWritable(..) but the error remained.. Im new to java and I wasn't sure if the new Text(..) implies declarations of the variable too..

Comment: Base problem for me is that the code listed in your question shouldn't compile, whereas the `Text field1 = ...` should.

Comment: @Tome You are right, I updated the question.

Comment: Now, we can see you declare variables *in* the for-loop, which mean they are only visible from *inside* that loop, so your `context.write(...)` cannot compile. I guess putting that line inside the loop will make it compile, but many that is not the business behavior your want.

Comment: Well you re right ! Thank you !